# Kohana module restify URL

Tags: rest, module, kohana

Hi I am trying to work with this module ->

http://kohana-modules.com/modules/michealmorgan/kohana-restify

It works great except when I use curl to send requests, if I send this

localhost/restify/test?id=1
then I get the value of id

If I do this

localhost/restify/test/1 or 
localhost/restify/test/index/1 I get routed to the defualt page (error page)

So I asume Index is mapped to GET ,so anything thats not test/index is routed, but I cant figure out how to allow it to accept it.

Has anyone solved this ?

thanks

```
if (trim(Request::detect_uri(), '/') == 'restify/test')
{
Route::set('restify/test', '<directory>(/<controller>(/<action>(id/<id>)))')
->defaults(array
(
'directory'     => 'restify', 
'controller'    => 'test'
```

Comment: You have to show us your bootstrap.php or we can't help you.

Comment: thats the thing, I dont think its the bootstrap because as soon as the module sees GET it goes to index anything else like index/44 is sent to default page . here it is.   
if (trim(Request::detect_uri(), '/') == 'restify/test')

{
 
Route::set('restify/test', '<directory>(/<controller>(/<action>(id/<id>)))')
  ->defaults(array
  (
   'directory'  => 'restify', 
   'controller'  => 'test'
  ));
}

Answer (score 0):

try inserting this in your bootstrap...

```
echo Debug::vars(trim(Request::detect_uri(), '/'));
```

if it does not equal restify/test when you curl the request, something is up and you might need to fix the module